# Paypal Express checkout not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, paypal-sandbox, paypal

I am trying to integrate Paypal using Express Checkout. I am following the [this example](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/express-checkout/integration-jsv4/basic-integration/) to make it work. I have setup sandbox account and `checkout` button show up without ant issue.

Problem happen when i click on the Button it open the popup window and ask for login details. after entering the the login details it open the sandbox account page but "your Order Summary section" is blank it doesn't show the amount as being passed by the API.

Below are image for both steps for your reference

Image 1 Button: [image]

Image 2: Paypal Login screen
[image]

Image 3 : Screen After Log in
[image]

I am not sure what i am doing wrong. This [video](https://www.paypal.com/us/webapps/mpp/one-touch-checkout) from paypal show it is pretty simple.

Test Code on my page.

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <br>Express Checkout </br>
        <div id="paypal-button">Pay Now</div>
        <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js"></script>       
        <script>
        paypal.Button.render({
            env: 'sandbox', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment
            client: {
                sandbox:    'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                production: 'xxxxxxxxx'
            },
            payment: function() {
                var env    = this.props.env;
                var client = this.props.client;
                return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
                    transactions: [
                        {
                            amount: { total: '1.00', currency: 'USD' }
                        }
                    ]
                });
            },
            commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow
            onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {
                // Optional: display a confirmation page here
                return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {
                    // Show a success page to the buyer
                });
            }
        }, '#paypal-button');
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your browser has a **developer** tools console ... any errors?

Comment: There are no error. It is  a copy paste from Paypal example.. Should run smoothly. To get over this i tested it with both personal & Business account

Comment: `It is a copy paste from Paypal example` ... except of course the `client:` object, right? You've changed `xxxxxxx` as required

Comment: I created the sandbox:    'ARjQ0K1Y8AOp-ZDRhCOOLsQcbzZyuScMNwxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: no need to post it (or even a part of it) - I just wanted to be clear that you followed step 1 of the instructions

Comment: THis is complete part of it has been taken out